# Springboot metric "process_files_open" shows large numbers for both "open" and "max"

Tags: spring-boot, grafana, metrics, spring-boot-actuator

- What I am trying to achieve:

Already published the metrics "process_files_open", and I want to create the correct visuals from it.

- What did I try:

I see the metric "process_files_open" and use it as query, in grafana cloud for example.

I even created a visual for the "open" and the "max"

[image]

- Issue:

The above visual is from the default "pet clinic" springboot application.

Issue 1: I containerized the application and ran it. The container itself is a jdk slim, and there are not even 1000000 total files in the container. Why would "max" be such a high number?

Issue 2: The default "pet clinic" springboot application does not open any file. It is not reading any input stream, not opening any key stores, not writing things to an output. Why would be there 300+ files opened?

- Question:

What do those "max" and "open" values represent?

How to build the proper visual to show them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The metric `process_files_open` refers to file descriptors used by the process itself. Even if you do not open a file directly from source code, there are files, which are accessed by java itself (e.g. libc.so, libjvm.so, input, output). You can show them by using for example `lsof -p <pid>`.

The max value is the value for the limit enforced by the operating system of open files. You can inspect the limits by using `cat /proc/<pid>/limits`.